# How to determine if firewall blocks access to Amazon EC2 without creating AWS account

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have been told that our company firewall might restrict access to Amazon EC2 network. What would be the quickest way to determine if a certain server will be able to access the EC2 instances, without actually going through the process of creating an AWS account and EC2 instances and then trying to ssh into the instances.

Comment: Ask the network admin?

Comment: What kind of access? ssh, http, ...?

Comment: Creating an AWS account and an EC2 instance takes about as long as you've spent asking this question and posting comments to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS publishes [their public IP address space](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1701).  You could probably try pinging some random IPs in those ranges and see if your packets get killed at the firewall.

Comment: Actually, Pinterest.com is hosted on EC2, so you could just hit that. Same thing for AirBnB.com.

Comment: TK100 needs SSH and HTTP access, so `nmap --traceroute` or `tcptraceroute` to ports 22 and 80 would likely be more informative than simple pinging.